# Fazer busca em um site

Tags: java

Boa tarde.. Preciso fazer um projeto em java no netbeans que o programa vá no site e busque o que foi digitado no campo de texto do programa. O meu tema é receitas e o site é o cybercook, digitando bolo na tela de busca do meu programa e clicando em buscar, devera abrir uma nova tela do meu programa com uma lista dos bolos que aparecem no site. Ao clicar em um dos bolos, terá que abrir uma nova tela com algumas informações do bolo. Não sei se ficou claro o que preciso fazer, ouvi falar da biblioteca jsoup pra buscar as coisas dentro do site, mas eu nao consegui usa-la para o que eu preciso, e ainda to com problemas nos eventos dos botões e da caixa de texto. se alguem puder me ajudar obrigado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que entendi dos comentarios tenho que fazer algo assim... Estou com duvida de como faço para o texto que for digitado no campo de texto ser salvo em alguma variavel algo do tipo, para que eu posso então, coloca-lo na parte do codigo onde esta escrito bolo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow amigo, isto é um pedido de software e não um problema real, portanto se caracteriza como off-topic, pois não é um problema que possa ser reproduzido ao meu ver. O que você já tentou?

Comment: Ola Gabriel, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. A comunidade é voltada a perguntas objetivas sobre programação e a sua está muito ampla. Podemos te ajudar em problemas específicos, mas não podemos fazer tudo por você. Traga suas dúvidas específicas junto com os detalhes do esforço que você já fez para resolvê-las e a comunidade irá te apoiar. Além disso recomendo uma visita a [help] e [ask], e também q faça o [tour]

Comment: Eu editei o port para tentar traduzir uma das minhas duvidas

Comment: Imagens não ajudam em muito Gabriel, tem que postar um exemplo que possa ser reproduzido. LEIA: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e depois edite a sua questão. :) boa sorte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma que está fazendo você está pegando todos os links (da página toda). Se seu objetivo é obter somente o link das receitas, você precisa inspecionar o código HTML para verificar onde são carregadas essas informações.

No site em questão, as receitas são carregadas em um div com id `resultado-busca`. Dentro dele, cada receita é inserida dentro de um div com classe `bloco-receita`.

Ainda assim, há muitos *links*, então é preciso ser mais restrito.
Pois bem, dentro de cada div com classe `bloco-receita`, há uma div com nome `foto-item` e é dentro desse div que está o *link* que aponta para a página da receita.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class BuscaReceitas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document pagina;
        try {
            pagina = Jsoup.connect("http://cybercook.com.br/resultado.php?ctr_busca=rapida&tp_busca_a=0&plv=bolo").get();

            Elements links = pagina.getElementById("resultado-busca")
                                   .getElementsByClass("bloco-receita");

            for(Element link : links.select(".foto-item > a")){
                System.out.println("Texto: " + link.attr("title"));
                System.out.println("Link: " + link.attr("href"));
            }
        } catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Obtive os seguintes resultados nos testes:

[image: output]

... a lista é extensa. **:P**